# When i try to use Javaanpr Jar in android. VM gets disconnected while creating object for the class in the Jar

Tags: android

```
public static Intelligence systemLogic;
/**
* @param args
*/
public String getNumber(String filepath) throws Exception{
String number1 = null;
Intelligence grabNumber = null;
grabNumber = new Intelligence(false);
number1 = grabNumber.recognize(new CarSnapshot(filepath));
}
```

It is failing while create instance itself

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: See the answer on another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27767618/2713162).

---

I assume the error happens while you're trying to initialize Intelligence object:

`grabNumber = new Intelligence(false);`

It happens because the Intelligence object in it's constructor is looking for `./config.xml` and cannot find it in your project.

1. One possible solution would be to find the `config.xml` file in the JavaANPR jar file and put it in your classpath (if you're using eclipse, your project's main directory).
2. Another solution would be to create your own project with the JavaANPR source code, and edit the loading of `config.xml` as I had done. I will opensource my version of [JavaANPR](https://github.com/oskopek/javaanpr) shortly.