# How to use javaanpr in Android app?

Tags: java, android, ocr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I would like to use this library for Car plate recognition in my Android app.

I red about JNI, but i'm still not able to get some good explained tutorial, how can i use use this library in my Android app.

http://javaanpr.sourceforge.net/

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: did you found any implementation. I tried the one from https://code.google.com/p/android-anpr/, but couldn't have expected result.

Comment: No, I did not find any working library :(

Answer (score 1):

In it's current state, you will not be able to use JavaANPR on Android. The problem is, that JavaANPR's core functions use the `java.awt` package quite heavily (for example [Photo.java](https://github.com/oskopek/javaanpr/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/javaanpr/imageanalysis/Photo.java)) and **Android doesn't support AWT** mostly (AWT contains native code, and Android has it's own `android.graphics` package). There have been some attempts to port AWT to Android, but AFAIK they all failed/died eventually.

Disclaimer: A while ago, I [forked JavaANPR](https://github.com/oskopek/javaanpr) in order to make it more library-like. It shouldn't be too hard to port the AWT code in JavaANPR to `android.graphics` though and you are more than welcome to submit a pull request!